# Automatically clicking a pre-defined region on a webpage?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to do something with Chrome's new speech recognition abilities with HTML5.

Following this page: http://www.filosophy.org/2011/03/talking-to-the-web-the-basics-of-html5-speech-input/ I see that you can easily hide the input area. But I'd like to take this further and automatically click the mic button (using javascript is possible?) without waiting for the user to click it.

Since the mic button resides on a specific region in the page always (dictated by me), is there a way to automate a click on a particular region on the webpage? So that the form doesn't wait for the user to click the button to populate itself. I'm guessing this should be possible with JS?

Please let me know, thanks :)

Comment: Please don't. I'd hate to consider the implications, legal, ethical or otherwise, of someone being able to programatically enable my microphone. Also, plain JavaScript, or with a JS library?

Comment: I understand the issue, but this is purely for a personal local project I conceived of. I'm open to any implementation -- in the end I don't want to wait for the user to click the button.

Comment: If it's enabled for a personal project, what would stop it being used for 'other' projects? I'd hope, quite strongly, that this is not possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, this is impossible for the same reason that you can't populate the value of a file input.

If you can turn the mic on without the user explicitly agreeing to it, then you could spy on what was being said near that mic.

Answer (score 0):

For security reasons, this will never be possible.